# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Application Context cannot be null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

can someone help me, that's my configuration class

```
 package net.king.cofingWeb;

import org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.thymeleaf.ITemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ITemplateResolver;

@Configuration
public class ThymeMvc extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

      @Bean
      public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
            ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
            resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
            resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            return resolver;
          }

    @Bean
    public ITemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return engine;
      }

    private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
      }









}
```

my pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

My Controller

```
    package net.king.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

import net.king.entities.Candidate;

@Controller
@EnableWebMvc
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }


}
```

my index file is in the template folder

my index file is in the template folder, after starting the server here is the result, I spend time solving but still no solutions
[image]

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Application Context cannot be null
    at org.thymeleaf.util.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:37) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresource.SpringResourceTemplateResource.<init>(SpringResourceTemplateResource.java:64) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver.computeTemplateResource(SpringResourceTemplateResolver.java:69) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.AbstractConfigurableTemplateResolver.computeTemplateResource(AbstractConfigurableTemplateResolver.java:1414) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.AbstractTemplateResolver.resolveTemplate(AbstractTemplateResolver.java:356) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:845) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) [thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) [thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:352) [thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) [thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1372) [spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118) [spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) [spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_241]

2020-06-02 01:31:14.282 ERROR 9236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception processing template (template: "index")] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Application Context cannot be null
    at org.thymeleaf.util.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:37) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresource.SpringResourceTemplateResource.<init>(SpringResourceTemplateResource.java:64) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver.computeTemplateResource(SpringResourceTemplateResolver.java:69) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.AbstractConfigurableTemplateResolver.computeTemplateResource(AbstractConfigurableTemplateResolver.java:1414) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.AbstractTemplateResolver.resolveTemplate(AbstractTemplateResolver.java:356) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:845) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:352) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1372) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_241]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample of a runnig config, you need to set a ApplicationContext attribute and             set it to resolver:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { CervejasController.class })
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        engine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
        return engine;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a spring mvc application as far as I understand, I think the issue is with your `@configuration` change the beans to :

```
@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    templateEngine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(messageSource());
    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
    // SpringResourceTemplateResolver automatically integrates with Spring's own
    // resource resolution infrastructure, which is highly recommended.
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    // HTML is the default value, added here for the sake of clarity.
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    // Template cache is true by default. Set to false if you want
    // templates to be automatically updated when modified.
    templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
    return templateResolver;
}
```

The `SpringTemplateEngine` class performs all of the configuration steps. Try using Spring classes for configuration instead of the Thymeleaf dependency ones.Use Spring classes instead of the Thymeleaf classes for configuring Thymeleaf so that the application context gets injected during bean creation.You are returning a `ThymeleafViewResolver` for view resolver but it is perfectly alright as it implements the `ViewResolver`, but the other two beans should be changed.

Also, if you plan on upgrading the spring version from 4 to 5 , also change the configuration to following :

```
@Configuration
public WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    // ...
}
```

as WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated in Spring5.If your application was a springboot application instead of the dependencies that you provided , use the following dependency for thymeleaf :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```